# Strapi V4 : what's the difference and goals of those two posts structures?

Tags: strapi

when getting an entity using an endpoint, I get something like

```
  {
      "data": {
          "id": 18,
          "attributes": {
              "title": "Brazil",
              "description": null,
              "private": false,
              "synced": false,
              "createdAt": "2019-09-02T21:26:18.000Z",
              "updatedAt": "2023-06-08T09:47:06.708Z",
              "publishedAt": "2019-09-02T21:26:18.000Z",
              "wp_id": 54,
              "wp_status": "publish",
              "track_count": 13,
              "thumbnail": {
                  "data": {
                      "id": 89,
                      "attributes": {
                          "url": "/uploads/havaianasbrazil_logohav_brasil_logo_green_bamboo_8810f4d4fa.jpg"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      },
      "meta": {}
  }
```

While when I get it using strapi.query, it's like

```
  {
    id: 18,
    title: 'Brazil',
    description: null,
    private: false,
    synced: false,
    createdAt: '2019-09-02T21:26:18.000Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-06-08T09:47:06.708Z',
    publishedAt: '2019-09-02T21:26:18.000Z',
    wp_id: 54,
    wp_status: 'publish',
    track_count: 13,
    thumbnail: {
      id: 89,
      url: '/uploads/havaianasbrazil_logohav_brasil_logo_green_bamboo_8810f4d4fa.jpg'
    }
  }
```

Note that in the first result is wrapped with `data` and `attributes` everywhere (eg. look at the *thumbnail* property).

Why is there a difference, when does it occurs, why, and when should I use one format or the other ?  Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I know is that the [transformResponse](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/main/packages/core/strapi/lib/core-api/controller/transform.js) function is responsible for embedding the data in `data` and `attributes`. That function is called by the core controllers (created with the [createCoreController factory](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/main/packages/core/strapi/lib/factories.js#L9)). And for custom controllers, Strapi recommends to use that function as well, as shown in their example code:
https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/controllers

As a result, the reponses by core controllers are pretty cumbersome to work with and developers do have a problem with it, as discussed in this Strapi forum thread:
https://forum.strapi.io/t/13400

There is a plugin which you can install on your Strapi project, which reverses that process by adding a middleware which flattens the response again:
https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-transformer

Your question is probably best suited in that Strapi forum thread.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to promote my zero conf plug too :) it should be faster because it isn’t middleware it’s just removes transformResponse function completely https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-untransform-response